# ConnectionFailedException : Websocket connection failed

Tags: websocket, jms, kaazing

I am taking over an iOS application connecting to the server through a Web socket connection using the [Kaazing Websocket (JMS edition) client side javascript library](http://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/).

I am using Phonegap for my iOS application and be able to test it both on Chrome and the iOS simulator. About 30% of the time I get a connection error from the library testing on chrome and 70% for testing on the iOS simulator/device. I get an Exception being thrown in the minified js library which just say "ConnectionFailedException : Websocket connection failed" Seems like this is a browser specific issue but I cannot do anything further about it.
I can't directly take a look at the server located in the UK but asking them for debug logs. So I asked for the logs from server and these are the errors that I spotted out that might be the reason:

> 2014-03-05 08:09:23,670 [NioProcessor-15] DEBUG session.revalidate - No WebSocket authorization timeout has been configured, so no revalidate period can be inferred.
>   2014-03-05 08:09:23,670 [NioProcessor-15] INFO  session.revalidate - WebSocket Session [176128] is not being re-validated because no timeout has been specified for the negotiated "x-kaazing-http-revalidate" extension.

Anybody have any idea about this `x-kaazing-http-revalidate` and if not, what is the proper way to debug these Websocket connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclaimer, I work at Kaazing.

`x-kaazing-http-revalidate` is a Kaazing HTTP extension, negotiated while establishing WebSocket connection. This is done by setting the authorization-timeout in the gateway-config.xml file (the configuration file we ship has an example). The intention of this extension is to periodically revalidate the user's authorization, because entitlements could change over the duration of a long-running connection.

`ConnectionFailedException : WebSocket connection failed`  can occur, if some intermediaries/proxies associated with the service providers inject an unknown or a suspicious header/s in the WebSocket connection request. If the injected header is unknown/suspicious, then Kaazing gateway will not complete the connection, to avoid intruders from eavesdropping. Using a secure TLS/SSL connection should resolve the intermediary related issues.

To debug and to setup a secure javascript client please follow instructions from the [documentation](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/jms_client_docs/dev-js/o_dev_js.html). You can also use *WebSocket-debug.js* instead of  *WebSocket.js* with script tags in the *jms-javascript.html* file for more logging. There is also a [Walkthrough: Deploy a JavaScript JMS App as a Hybrid iOS App](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/jms_client_docs/dev-js/hybrid_ios_walkthrough.html).

Comment: Thanks, I had contacted with the server guy and he gave me a new JS client and it's working fine now. I had no idea looking at the generated JS client file.